# I want to create an array from multiple tableView selection

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary, nsindexpath

```
//this gives me an array for multiple rows selected in a tableView.

let rowsSelected = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!.map{$0.row}
```

the print statement gives me a result like this for selection of row 2 and 5.....[2.5].

I now want to delete the two lines from the current list. I am struggling to find the right concept for creating the reduced array. Dictionary or working with NSIndexPath?

Comment: Remove your items from array and reload your tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vadian's answer is close, but it's dangerous; see my comment on his answer.

To fix it, you must first *reverse* the array of indices to be deleted. To see why, run the following lines in a playground:

```
let indicesToDelete = [4, 8]
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
let goodReducedArray = indicesToDelete.reverse().map { array.removeAtIndex($0) }
goodReducedArray  // prints ["i","e"]
let badReducedArray = indicesToDelete.map { array.removeAtIndex($0) }
badReducedArray   // barfs EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
```

So the corrected version of @vadian's code will be:

```
if let selectedIndexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
   selectedIndexPaths.reverse().map{tableData.removeAtIndex($0.row)}
   tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(selectedIndexPaths, withRowAnimation:.Fade)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name of your data source array is `tableData`, you can use these lines.

The items in the data source array and in the table view must be removed simultaneously, the `sort` and `forEach` functions are used to remove the items starting at the highest index.

```
if let selectedIndexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
   let indexes = selectedIndexPaths.map{$0.row}.sort(>) // sort descending
   indexes.forEach{tableData.removeAtIndex($0)}
   tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(selectedIndexPaths, withRowAnimation:.Fade)
}
```

Comment: NO! The `tableData.removeAtIndex()` calls are not atomic, even though they're called in a `map`, because one or more of them may reduce the size of the array enough to be shorter than some of the remaining indices. Instead, either *reverse* the array of paths to be deleted (thus ensuring that higher-numbered paths will always be deleted before lower-numbered ones), or filter the array such that it skips elements at the indices to be deleted.

Comment: Very good point, thanks, I updated my answer with a reliable version